# Are there surfaces with radial curvature but no radial symmetry?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curvature, symmetry

Let $S$ be a surface, and let $g$ be a smooth Riemannian metric on $S$.

Let $p \in S$, and set $r(x)=d_g(p,x)$. Suppose that the curvature of $S$ at a point $q \in S$ depends only on $r(q)$, at least for points sufficiently close to $p$.

Does there always exist a coordinate $\theta$ defined on some punctured ball $U=B_r(p) \setminus\{p\}$ such that on $U$, $g$ is given by
$$g=dr^2+q^2(r)d\theta^2. \tag{1}$$

---

I am quite certain we can always "complete" $r$ to an orthogonal coordinate system $(r,\theta)$, i.e. find $\theta$ such that $$g=dr^2+q^2(r,\theta)d\theta^2. \tag{2}$$
A computation gives
$$
K(r,\theta)=-\frac{q_{rr}}{q},
$$
which should be independent of $\theta$. ($K$ is the curvature of $S$).

---

Finding a coordinate $\tilde \theta$ and $\tilde q(r)$ such that
$$g=dr^2+\tilde q^2(r)d\tilde \theta^2, $$
is equivalent to solving
$$
q(r,\theta)d\theta=\tilde q(r)d\tilde \theta.
$$
Taking the exterior derivative, we get
$$
q_r dr \wedge d\theta=\frac{\tilde q_r q}{\tilde q}dr \wedge d\theta,
$$
so
$$
q_r=\frac{\tilde q_r q}{\tilde q}=F(r)q, \tag{3}
$$
where $F(r):=\frac{\tilde q_r}{\tilde q}$.

Differentiating this, we get
$$
q_{rr}=F'(r)q+F(r)q_r,
$$
so finally
$$
-K(r)=\frac{q_{rr}}{q}=F'(r)+F^2(r). \tag{4}
$$

So, to construct such $\tilde q$, we first need to find a solution $F$ to the Riccati type equation $(4)$, and then check whether equation $(3)$ holds. This seems to be only the starting point...

Comment: Note that all you have to do is change variables with $\tilde\theta = \int h(\theta)\,d\theta$ and this then looks like the usual $\theta$-independent situation. So, up to reparametrization, it reduces to the symmetric case.

Comment: Thank you; this is a great comment which made me think deeper about the problem! I completely agree with you that a factor of $h(\theta)d\theta$ can be "assimilated", since we can define a new coordinate $\tilde \theta$ by setting $h(\theta)d\theta=\tilde d\theta$ as you suggested. So my suggestion $h(\theta)d\theta$ was not really "intrinsically interesting", just a "wrong" choice of parametrization. After some more thinking, I have now changed the question into something which I think is more interesting. I will be happy to hear your thoughts.